# How to set column blank if column contains alphanumeric characters in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have to fetch 1 column of MSISDN from table.

the result looks like as in image,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWXgu.png)

in some rows it returns string like nt&'gt;1 every time it is not same.

I want to set column blank without dropping the row if this occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select case
         when REGEXP_LIKE(MSISDN, '[A-Za-z]') then null
         else MSISDN
       end as MSISDN
from MyTable
```

Comment: @AnujBedge Regular expressions are overkill for this and this will replace any row where there is at least one non-alphabetic values. The OP's data shows that the other values in the column are numeric; so they will all be replaced.

Comment: @MT0 I mistakenly left the `^` in from testing... My bad

Comment: NP Jhon I have adjusted as per my query Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You could solve this with a CASE statement in SQL

```
SELECT CASE WHEN MSISDN = 'nt&gt;1' THEN '' ELSE MSISDN END AS MSISDN
```

Answer (score 1):

You could compare the strings or you could use the `LIKE` operator. Some options are:

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN MSISDN = 'nt&gt;1'            THEN NULL -- match nt&gt1;
         WHEN MSISDN LIKE '%&gt;%'          THEN NULL -- match &gt; anywhere in the string
         WHEN LOWER( MSISDN ) LIKE '%&lt;%' THEN NULL -- match &lt; ignoring case
         WHEN MSISDN LIKE '%&%;%'           THEN NULL -- match & followed later by ;
         ELSE MSISDN
       END AS parsed_msisdn
FROM   your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Use REPLACE String function for replace your particular string :

```
  SELECT REPLACE(Your_columnName,'nt&''gt;1','')
  FROM Your_table
```

Comment: it will be a better answer if you describe your code there!